# c programming beginner (arrays)

Tags: c

The question asks to input a sentence (up to 20 characters). If for any part of the input there contains the word bad, it is replaced with ---. For example, input bad dog would output: --- dog, another example is input: bade and output: ---e.

I was only able to set up the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c, i;
    int counts[20];

    for (i = 0; i <= 19; i=i+1)
    {
        counts[i] = 0;
    }

    c = getchar();
    while (c!= '\n')
    {
        if ()
    }
}
```

Comment: You've not actually asked a question.

Comment: My advice would be to input the whole sentence; and once input is finished, then go back and do the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char sentence[20+1];
    char *p;

    scanf("%20[^\n]", sentence);
    if(NULL!=(p = strstr(sentence, "bad"))){//only once!,,
        memcpy(p, "---", 3);
    }
    printf("%s\n", sentence);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should downvote because it's handing out an answer to homework or upvote because by the time the op has understood what's going on here he's learned more about C than he would solving this task normally.

Comment: You would probably want a while loop as there may be more than one occurence.

Comment: It is a simple example. example to be a stepping stone first is required for people who do not see `int` and `char`. Must be processed in the loop actually.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your example to a simple and basic program .Try to understand it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
int len,i;
char counts[20];
printf("enter the string (string length must be less than 20 characters) \n");
printf("and hit enter button after a string is entered\n");

i=0;  // Data length count
do            
{
    counts[i]=getchar();
    i++
}while(counts[i] != '\n');
i--;
len=i;
counts[i]='\0';          // Terminate string with null character  

for(i=0;i<(len-2);i++)    // Checks entire string for the word "bad" and if found it is replaced by "---" 
{
    if(counts[i] == 'b')
    {           
        if(counts[i+1] == 'a'
        {   
            if(counts[i+2]='d';
            {
                counts[i]  ='-';
                counts[i+1]='-';
                counts[i+2]='-';
            }
        }
    }           
}

for(i=0;i<len;i++)       // Displays the result
putchar(counts[i]);

getch();
}
```

Comment: you forgot `#` at first line :P

Comment: Please don't use `gets`, especially when trying to teach someone

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char c;
    int i;
    char counts[20] = { 0 };

    for(i=0; (i<20) & (c!= '\n'); )
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == 'b')
    {
            c = getchar();
            if (c == 'a')
        {
                c = getchar();
                if (c == 'd')
            {
                counts[i+2] = '-';
                counts[i+1] = '-';
                counts[i] = '-';
                i=i+3;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                counts[i+2] = c;
                counts[i+1] = 'a';
                counts[i] = 'b';
                i=i+3;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            counts[i+1] = c;
            counts[i] = 'b';
            i=i+2;
            continue;
        }
    }
    counts[i] = c;
    i=i+1;
    }
printf("new string: %s\n", counts);
}

> Blockquote
```

Comment: " 45 is the ascii value for '-' " - why don't you just write `'-'` then?

Comment: Your code has a lot of mistakes. `c` should be `int`. It overflows the buffer. It's a lot more complicated than it needs to be. The indenting and  placement of braces is horrible and misleading , so the code is hard to follow. It reads an uninitialized variable. It uses `&` . It doesn't handle "ba\n" and several other such cases.

Comment: May be i have complicated it for you. You have to look at the reception capability for the person asked the question. i don't want to use strstr() etc and confuse him. he might want in simple methods he knows. I can't understand how it overflows when we are using ascii characters? i accept that it doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: If someone types `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbar` you write past the end of `counts`.

Comment: You are Great!, You are checking all cases. Great to see such kind of dedication in every small program. Thanks, i will improve

Comment: It is a simple example. example to be a stepping stone first is required for people who do not see int and char. Must be processed in the loop actually. from  BLUEPIXY post